# how can I chaced size of input in html/css

Tags: html, css, forms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlWx7.png)
I am trying to resize my form boxes but I couldn't I changed height,width and font-size but only space changed between name form and password form

```
<div class="container">
    
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
            <br>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        </form>
        
        
  </div>
```

I am trying to resize my form boxes but I couldn't I changed height,width and font-size